# adding/embedding youtube videos in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I want to add youtube videos thumbnails to my asp.net website like the videos section in http://jtsplatmaster.com/. On this website, If you click the right thumbnails, video will start playing in the main section without page refresh. Which control so I need to use. I know that object tag can be used to embed youtube videos in asp.net page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I found this API http://youtube.codeplex.com/. May be helpful for someone in future.

Regards,
Asif Hameed